# Python Script Dependencies from Imported Files

Tags: python

I have an auxillary python file that looks like this:

Aux.py

```
import pyodbc, sqlalchemy

def Func1(param1, param2):
    return something
```

It basically standardizes some database connections I use. In that file I have to pull in libraries like pyodbc, sqlalchemy, etc. to establish the database connections.

In other projects I just use a script like this to use my functions:

main.py

```
module_path = r'C:\Users\mypath'
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)

from Aux_File import Func1, Func2
```

The issue I run into is my main file is running in a different venv so I still need to make sure i have these libraries loaded into this other venv. Is there a way to package my Aux.py file so it contains all its own dependencies?

Comment: It would be worth considering using Python's own [packaging system](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) instead of rolling your own dependency management. Then you just `pip install path/to/despondency` inside the venv instead of doing path fiddling at runtime.

Comment: @Brian thank you! This is what I was looking for but for whatever reason when I searched for this all I could find were docs on creating an executable.